# Raspberry Pi DHT 11 sensor not working.I get None None

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, sensor, python-3, dht22

[image: photo of wiring]Have integrated Raspberry pi4 with a DHT sensor.
The data pin is connected to pin GPIO 26

Have tried connecting the VCC to both 3.3V and 5V

Have tried with both Adafruit_DHT.DHT11 and Adafruit_DHT.DHT22 in the code for the same sensor but I get  None None

```
import Adafruit_DHT

# Sensor should be set to Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,
# Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, or Adafruit_DHT.AM2302.
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
pin = 26

while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    print(temperature, humidity)
```

Output:

None None

Is the sensor broken??Should I replace it or is there any other solution??

Thanks in Advance

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwlxR.jpg)

Comment: Does your DHT11 contain a 10K pull up resistor? Post a photo of your wiring.

Comment: @CoderMike Have posted a photo please check it out

Comment: Do _not_ connect the DHT11 to 5V on a Raspberry Pi. Since most of these boards contain a pull-up resistor, this might damage the GPIO pins.

Comment: @PMF ok..but i still don't get required output

Comment: It is normal that these senors sometimes require multiple attempts to deliver a correct result, but that it never works is quite unusual. Mine work fine with a very similar setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pigpio_dht import DHT11, DHT22

gpio = 4 # BCM Numbering

sensor = DHT11(gpio)
#sensor = DHT22(gpio)

result = sensor.read()
print(result)
```

This worked for me. Before running the code enter the below commands on the terminal

```
sudo pigpiod #Start daemon

pigs pud 4 u # Set internal pull up
```

If pigpio-dht is not installed enter `pip3 install pigpio-dht` and run the above program

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code.

[pigpio DHT example](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_code/DHT.py).

It needs the pigpio daemon to be running.

`sudo pigpiod`

Then assuming the script file is called DHT.py run with

`./DHT.py 26` # if connected to GPIO 26

or

`./DHT.py 7` # if connected to pin 26

See https://pinout.xyz/ for the mapping between pin and GPIO numbers.

If it doesn't work either the wiring or the sensor is faulty.

Comment: if run sudo pigpiod i get " 2021-03-05 18:46:15 initInitialise: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid Can't initialise pigpio library"

if i run ./DHT.py 26 i get   " ./dht2.py: line 1: import: command not found
./dht2.py: line 5: sensor: command not found
./dht2.py: line 13: pin: command not found"

Its a python file why run as a shell script?

I have uploaded the photo of wiring, please check it out

Comment: Is the pigpio daemon running?  Does `pigs t` return a number?  Use `python DHT.py 26` if you prefer. The wiring seems okay.

Comment: If I give command "sudo pigs t" I get  "381125293"
If I run sudo "python3 dht2.py 26" I get "None None"

Comment: Please run the script I provided.  It MUST be called DHT.py (not dht.py, not x.py, not dht2.py).

Comment: For the command  python DHT.py 26 I get:

1614974667.288 26 3 0.0 0.0
1614974669.559 26 3 0.0 0.0

1614974671.828 26 3 0.0 0.0
1614974674.099 26 3 0.0 0.0

1614974676.371 26 3 0.0 0.0
1614974678.642 26 3 0.0 0.0

1614974680.913 26 3 0.0 0.0

Here 3 means no response from the sensor.

could you please say should I replace the sensor or is there any other option?

Comment: I suggest you add a close-up photo of the module you are using.  I don't recognise it, I usually just see the blue part.  A wiring problem is much more likely than a module fault.

Comment: Have added a close up image of the module please do check out the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwlxR.jpg

Comment: Looks okay.  Are you sure yellow is connected to a ground at the Pi end.  I can't make it out.

Comment: yeah its connected to ground

Comment: I changed the sensor but still am I get none...so it's not a fault with the sensor..Can we connect on skype ?